# How can I create v-models on deep arrays or objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to create several `v-models` of random properties of a deep array (arrays/objects attributes position can be changed anytime). I managed to do what I want as follows. However, there will be several fields to be rendered in different places on the page, so a `v-for` is out of consideration. Is it possible to simplify this code?

```js
<template>
  <div class="builder">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="block">
        <input v-model="template[headTagIndex].children[headTagAttributesIndex].children[headTagAttributesAllIndex].attributes['font-family']" placeholder="Fonte geral" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor">
      <div v-if="compiledTemplate" v-html="compiledTemplate.html"/>
      <div v-else>Loading</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ads"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const {$mjml} = useNuxtApp()

const template = ref([
  {
    "tagName": "mj-head",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "mj-attributes",
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "mj-all",
            "attributes": {
              "font-family": "Comic sans-serif"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tagName": "mj-body",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "mj-section",
        "attributes": {
          "background-color": "red"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "mj-column",
            "attributes": {
              "padding-top": "100px",
              "padding-bottom": "100px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "tagName": "mj-text",
                "attributes": {
                  "align": "center",
                  "color": "#F45E43"
                },
                "content": "Testing component"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tagName": "mj-section",
        "attributes": {
          "full-width": "full-width",
          "background-color": "blue"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "mj-column",
            "attributes": {
              "padding-top": "100px",
              "padding-bottom": "100px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "tagName": "mj-text",
                "attributes": {
                  "align": "center",
                  "color": "#F45E43"
                },
                "content": "Testing component"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tagName": "mj-section",
        "attributes": {
          "background-color": "pink"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "mj-column",
            "attributes": {
              "padding-top": "100px",
              "padding-bottom": "100px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "tagName": "mj-text",
                "attributes": {
                  "align": "center",
                  "color": "#F45E43"
                },
                "content": "Testing component"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tagName": "mj-section",
        "attributes": {
          "full-width": "full-width",
          "background-color": "teal"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "mj-column",
            "attributes": {
              "padding-top": "100px",
              "padding-bottom": "100px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "tagName": "mj-text",
                "attributes": {
                  "align": "center",
                  "color": "#F45E43"
                },
                "content": "Testing component"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
])

const headTagIndex = template.value.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-head')
console.log(headTagIndex)
const headTagAttributesIndex = template.value[headTagIndex].children.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-attributes')
console.log(headTagAttributesIndex)
const headTagAttributesAllIndex = template.value[headTagIndex].children[headTagAttributesIndex].children.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-all')
console.log(headTagAttributesAllIndex)

const compiledTemplate = computed(() => $mjml({
  "tagName": "mjml",
  "children": template.value
}))
</script>
```

The parts that need to be optimized are:

`v-model="template[headTagIndex].children[headTagAttributesIndex].children[headTagAttributesAllIndex].attributes['font-family']"`

And:

````js
const headTagIndex = template.value.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-head')
console.log(headTagIndex)
const headTagAttributesIndex = template.value[headTagIndex].children.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-attributes')
console.log(headTagAttributesIndex)
const headTagAttributesAllIndex = template.value[headTagIndex].children[headTagAttributesIndex].children.findIndex((tag) => tag.tagName === 'mj-all')
console.log(headTagAttributesAllIndex)```
````

Comment: Just don't use v-model for the sake of v-model and desugar it to value prop with update:value listener

Comment: @EstusFlask can you provide a quick sample on how would you do it?

Comment: Depends on the case, it's quite convoluted at this point and it's unclear if it's more complex that you show. I'd likely use v-model on a simple ref like `<input v-model="headFontFamilyRef"` and make the whole "template" a computed instead of ref, e.g. `"font-family": headFontFamilyRef.value`

Comment: you could consider provide/inject (maybe better for your case)

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Comment: "If you want to include the name of the language/library/framework/tool, do it in regular English, not as a bracketed tag." Don't see why OP isn't allowed to specify in the title that it's Vue and not Nuxt or something else. But hey...

Answer (score 1):

You can find `attributes` in one line by using [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=uk):

```
const attributes = template.value.find(tag => tag.tagName === 'mj-head')
   ?.children?.find(tag => tag.tagName === 'mj-attributes')
   ?.children?.find(tag => tag.tagName === 'mj-all')
   ?.attributes;
```

Then `v-model` will look like this:

```
<input v-model="attributes['font-family']" placeholder="Fonte geral" type="text"/>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNrtV11P2zAU/StW9lCQSGCCvbAWtE0gbQ9s2ngjPKTJTWpwbMt2SlGV/77rfDROSRiCPUxT+9DU9r3H9+PYzVl7n6QMlgV4p95Ux4pKQzSYQp6FnOZSKEPWREFKSpIqkZMJmk5CHvJYcG2IgVyyyACZWaO9m5ATsrZfhISeibKrKIfQO8VBfucvIEpC76BdjheUJQq4Xa8c7adxHgaIjFF0XhjQG5hnoLbgRiAZ62HVVu5Gp9sg1iAV3PhplFP2WEN9ETmNiY649jUomoZe36l0h87gtv3ZzFXjsgpotI5zkeCub6ijhthQgQ69Ij6TdOjNo/g+U6LgiR8LJlSNpQAb2hnWcb+9KbhDkffDe2FfZJQklGe+EbJGe390JFdPkFzTuTBG5D3rrdY9CWM0s4HshjM0sDIDUb0gx8aI0azaHoMBbgD7MQBWxdp1693lyYeLk+Pt/IZybH0RmmOg1vsatMF6kVjgtcCr6W2fHskdbo9yfrPr36ZrWjDmP9DELGoUd9xLdYzZc1ZgADtq76j9r1F7mK+S8vsdX3d8/Q+vYgMRvqPtqL2j9iup7b5Zh/x2/2OnX7oyoIJpxUywjPDfP0gpT/awpGR2RvARNNUls9mMTBo5M9m3qOdB26vzP3p1O77Cl7HWqYPBbKaHtXJDzYaDNg0cETKlXBaGLP1cJMBmbuNvJo6KmdyGHkG3GBaCJaDQ8tL2hWSg7PEj5lECTtaUOqyx56p+SgVn63UnBstyemjnbGRONN6BZzTWPaVZcKcFR8lZEc9SIJeUgfou7e3iUtKSkImHb9WcUQU4sgfi+4H5O41ny1LphwKUYks8Dps1E6kMGqZd/LpyjwceGJEUrDk8I4s/QeOlUd+A1uwzXlUYtmNXRfu1Es5I42t9sUJu6zYpG2gn8EIPxTQKx9HUu3CPg5OGvqVX/gZ+TjTR)